# MySQL Use WHERE statement to target particular row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

[image]I'm trying to query a table that focused on 3 different columns. I have columns nid, vid and title. I have to go through each nid value, grab the highest vid of each  nid value, once I get the highest vid I then have to get the title that's in the same row of the vid. Ultimately I'll need a list of each title. I have the 1st two steps down. The only part I need help with is grabbing the correct title content because once again it has to be the title that's in the same row as the highest vid. I thought a where statement would be a good way to do it but I'm stuck. Attached is a screenshot of the table.

```
$queryNodeRevision = "SELECT nid, MAX(vid) as vid, title FROM node_revision WHERE title = vid GROUP BY nid";
    // line above creates variable $queryNodeRevision > 

    $results = mysqli_query($connection, $queryNodeRevision) or die("Bad Query: $results");
    // line above creates variable $results > actually queries that database and passes in variable "$queryNodeRevision"

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
      // line above creates while loop that loops through > $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)
      // $row is variable that's set to mysqli_fetch_array (with variable $results being passed in)
      // mysqli_fetch_array > creates an associate array for each row in a table
      // $results > variable that's being passed into associative array that represents the variable that's querying "SELECT nid FROM node_revision";
      $currentNID = $row['nid'];
      // line above creates variable that represents the current 'nid' of row (aka the key)
      // $row['nid'] = gets the key # of the current 'nid'
      $currentVID = $row['vid'];
      // line above creates variable that represents the current value of the 'vid' (the number you want to compare)
      // $row['vid'] = gets the value of the current 'vid'  
      $theTitleIWant = $row['title'];
      // line above creates variable that represents the current value of the 'title'
      // $row['title'] = gets the value of the current 'title'  
      echo "<h1>" . $row['title'] . "</h1>";
      // line prints out desired 'title' into h1 tag
    } // line closes while loop
```

Below is the line with the where statement I'm trying to accomplish my code with.

```
$queryNodeRevision = "SELECT nid, MAX(vid) as vid, title FROM node_revision WHERE title = vid GROUP BY nid";[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider running your aggregate query (leaving out any reference to *title*) that joins back to the unit level table. Below returns the *title* corresponding to highest *vid* for each *nid*.

```
SELECT n.nid, n.vid, n.title
FROM node_revision n
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT nid, MAX(vid) as max_vid 
    FROM node_revision 
    GROUP BY nid
   ) AS agg
ON agg.nid = n.nid AND agg.max_vid = n.vid
```